# Aggregate by time and return the latest value in MuleSoft

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have an API that continuously receives key value pairs throughout the day. We use a time based aggregator to batch all the values received in 30 minute batches and send it to the server for processing. The API might receive the same key values at different times, for instance:

```
Call 1: {key="A", value=5}

Call 2: {key="A", value=6}

Call 3: {key="A", value=7}

Call 4: {key="B", value=10}

Call 5: {key="A", value=1}
```

Currently, the time based aggregator provides me with an `ArrayList` containing all the above key value pairs at the end of 30 minutes. However, my requirement is to only receive the latest value for each key. The end result of the examples above should be the following:

```
[{"A":1, "B":10}]
```

That is, the aggregator should only return the latest value for each key. I am not even sure if I need to use an aggregator in this case. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add some details, like the aggregator configuration (in XML), version of Mule.

Comment: Depends on if it's mule4 or 3.x.
I would put a dataweave after the aggregator and sort the records in the array by timestamp added, then I would pick the last one (or first one), and use it in a response.